# How to connect two variables in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I am building project using laravel + vue. Currently I return data from controller to view - users and user_datas. How I can connect that two variables and then display it together in v-for?

That two tables are connected using relationships in laravel.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: There's nothing to show. I need to know what to do. For example connect it using json_encode if it is possible etc.

Comment: You could definitely show how you're referencing the data in Vue and what you've tried so far. Then, after also adding an explanation of what isn't working as expected, that will provide potential answerers with a lot more context than simply asking how to "connect two variables" from laravel and then "display it together" in Vue (which is a pretty broad question).

Answer (score 1):

You can use laravel relations, and get the data in single variable. 
Then there will be no need to merge two variables.
you can do in your User model like this:

```
public function user_data() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\UserData');
}
```

where UserData will be your second model with whome you will create relation.

in controller you will write lik this:

```
 $users = User::with('user_datas')->get();
 return response()->json(['data'=>$users]);
```

then in your vue file

```
<div v-for="user in users">
    <h1>{{user.first_name}}</h1>
    <ul>
        <li v-for="user_data in user.user_datas">{{user_data.title}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```